# React Native Firebase Change initialRoute if logged in

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I'm using React Native 0.36 and Firebase. How do I make the homepage of the app change if a user is logged in. I tried an if statement in renderScene but it gives this error:

[image: React Native Firebase initialRoute error]

### index.ios.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {
  AppRegistry,
  Navigator,
} from 'react-native';

import firebase from 'firebase';
import Login from './Login';
import Home from './Home';

function renderScene(route, navigator) {
    return <route.component route={route} navigator={navigator} />;
}

export default class Snip extends Component {
  renderScene(route, navigator){ 
      return <route.component navigator={navigator} />
  }

  render() {
    var that = this;
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
      if(user) {
        return (
          <Navigator
            initialRoute={{component: Home}}
            renderScene={that.renderScene}/>
        )
      } else{
        return (
          <Navigator
            initialRoute={{component: Login}}
            renderScene={that.renderScene}/>
        )
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things that are wrong with the code from the question.

1. You cannot return a react element inside of a firebase callback
2. Firebase takes a moment to return if the user exists. So I have to create a loading state that get updated. When firebase is done.

### index.ios.js

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react';

  import {
    AppRegistry,
    Navigator,
    View,
    Text,
  } from 'react-native';

  import firebase from 'firebase';
  import Login from './Login';
  import Home from './Home';


  function renderScene(route, navigator) {
      return <route.component route={route} navigator={navigator} />;
  }

  export default class Snip extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { 
        user: null,
        loading: false
      };
    }

    componentWillMount() {
      var that = this;
      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        if(user) {
          that.setState({
            user: user,
            loading: false
          })
        }else{
          that.setState({
            loading: false
          })
        }
      });
    }

    renderScene(route, navigator){ 
        return <route.component navigator={navigator} />
    }

    render() {
      if(this.state.loading){
        return <View><Text>loading</Text></View>;
      }else if(this.state.user){
        return(
          <Navigator
            initialRoute={{component: Home}}
            renderScene={this.renderScene}/>
          )
      }else{
         return (
           <Navigator
             initialRoute={{component: Login}}
             renderScene={this.renderScene}/>
         )   
      }
    }
  }
```